# I want to make responsive dashboard in React.js using Material UI - Any helpful and authentic helping material?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, responsive, dashboard

I am making a responsive UI design in React.js using material UI which consideration I have to follow and can make the best and easy approach to achieve a responsive UI dashboard - I am looking for the best helping resources, documentations and blogs..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the material-ui installation and its components with react please kindly follow the below documentation

https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/

And if you want a ready-made dashboard/any-other-templates template that is made with material-UI + react then you can find it below the URL

https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/templates/

And to get a complete understanding of how to use it in to react you can check the below URL

https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-material-ui-for-react-material-design-for-react-364b2688b555

Answer (score 0):

You can always check out the existing solutions. I suggest you try [Materio MUI admin](https://themeselection.com/item/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/).

I have seen their coding standards and those are awesome. You won't regret it checking it out.

Still, if you want to go on your own there are plenty of YouTube videos & Udemy courses out there.

If you are an experienced developer then just go straight to the MUI docs.